# How to update content on flutter web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have a created an application using flutter web and deployed it using a hosting platform.
Now that I have done some modification in the application and want to update it.

The changes shows on localhost using the command 'flutter run -d chrome'
but it won't reflect on live site. I am using the command 'flutter build web'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `flutter build web`, the local "finalized" copy of the site is updated. Refer to your hosting provider for instructions to update your site.

Eg. Firebase Hosting:
`firebase deploy --only hosting` after you have set your public directory to `build/web` in your `.firebaserc`

Comment: It did help. There was some problem was with the hosting provider, not with flutter.